# Plotting a piecewise function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I've been trying to plot a piecewise function:

y(t)=a*sin(2*pi *f *t) for 0 < t <= 1/(2f)

y(t)=0 for 1/(2f) < t < 1/f

ranging from t=0 to t=3.

Can anyone help me plot this without using the "piecewise" command and instead creating a function possibly with for loops and if statements?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to stack overflow! Your question is not very clear - what do you want to achieve? What have you tried? Why did it not work? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask might help you to improve it!

Answer (score 1):

in matlab, usually plots are done by computing the x/y values in a discretized grid.

```
f=2;
a=1;
t=0:0.01:3;
y=zeros(size(t));
y(t<=1/(2*f))=a*sin(2*pi*f*t(t<=1/2/f));
plot(t,y)
```

another way to create such a piece-wise function is to create a dedicate function or anonymous function to compute this in real time. For example

```
y=@(t,f,a) (t<=1/(2*f) & t>=0).*sin(2*pi*f*t)*a;
plot(t,y(t,f,a))
```

Comment: I'm clearly not used to asking questions on this site;;; Could you plz take a look at what I'm doing wrong? I posted my new question below.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying sth like this:

function [rate] = y(a,f,t)
for t = (0:3)
if  t <= (1 / (2 * f))
    rate = a * sin(2 * pi * f * t);
else
    rate = 0;
end
end
end

and then call: plot (t, y(a,f,t)) to plot the graph. Could you correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: several issues: 1) your function y defines t inside, so, you do not have to pass on t to y because it already knows it. 2) but the issue then is your t has a fixed range. to make it flexible, you should write your y to convert a single value of t using it as an input. Basically, remove the for loop. 3) your t=0:3 vector is too sparse - 0:3 means [0 1 2 3] with 1 as spacing, it is not enough to show the curve.